# Confusing Git message when there is nothing to commit

Tags: git

I have this when I run `git status` on one of my folder :

[image]

I dont understand what this means concerning the tracking of my files.
I try to run `git add .` then `git commit` but I get

```
"On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean"
```

Why do I have this red notation here that seems to notify me that some files where not commited ?

Comment: Please,check your permission on git repository.

Comment: `st` is not a standard git command; you will have to explain what your `git st` alias does.

Comment: @torek git st stands for git status

Comment: @SoumyaDas, thanks, can you explain how to do that ?

Comment: That's not standard output for `git status`.  Normal output would start with `On branch <something>` (if you're on a branch) or `HEAD detached ...` (if not), followed by more lines that do not begin with '`## master...origin/master`.  In fact, your `git commit` output is normal `git status` output, which is to be expected if there is nothing to commit.  (If I had to guess, your `st` alias actually prints something on its own and then invokes `git log`, perhaps.)

Comment: Please type `git config alias.st` and tell us what it prints: you may have some options in your `git st` alias that we don't know about, and that would be good to know about to give you a correct answer.

Comment: @rmunn it prints status -sb

Comment: So your `git st` alias runs `status` with the `--short` and `--branch` options. The `## master...origin/master` line you're seeing is what `git status -sb` prints when you're on the `master` branch, which is set up to track the `origin/master` branch. This has nothing to do with whether or not your files are tracked.

Comment: I suspect, however, that there's nothing wrong with your Git repository, and you're just misunderstanding the output of `git status`. It will ONLY show you files in your repository that need action (e.g., they're new or changed and haven't been committed yet). Files that haven't been changed since your last commit won't show up in `git status`, because they're perfectly fine and need no action. So what I think it happening is that your files in that repo have *already* been committed earlier, and that's why `git st` isn't showing you anything but the branch tracking information.

Comment: Please don't post an image of your problem "code" but paste the code instead. Using an image makes that part of the question non-searchable and thus doesn't allow others to find it in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now that we know what your `git st` alias does (`git status -sb` = show short status including branch and upstream branch), we can answer where the red `origin/master` comes from: that's the upstream branch, shown in red because red is the default color for showing upstream branches in `git status -sb` output.

(For some reason, upstream branches default to blue in `git branch -vv` output, but red in `git branch -sb`.  The current branch defaults to green in both.  All of these assume you have colors turned on.)

If you mean that the one in your *prompt* is red, there's no easy way to tell from here, since prompt-setting is something you do with shell setup, and the colors are usually selected by whatever code you used to do that.